# Mellin transform of a shifted function

Tags: calculus

I have an application where it would be very useful to take the Mellin transform of a shifted function. Specifically 
\begin{equation}
M(f(y-x))(y \rightarrow s) = \int_{y=0}^{\infty} f\left(y-x\right) y^{s-1}\, dy.
\end{equation}
Assuming $x>0$, the substitution $y=\alpha x$, hence $dy = x d\alpha$, leads to
\begin{equation}
x^{s} M(f((\alpha - 1)x))(\alpha \rightarrow s) 
= M(f(\alpha - 1))(\alpha \rightarrow s). 
\end{equation}
I have good reason to think this result is wrong, but cannot see the error. Does anyone know if the above has a simple answer?